# Turn line graph into bars with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have this fragment of code (stacked is a var that i set when click on a button)

```
    if(stacked){
        d3.selectAll('path').transition()
        .delay(function(d) { 
            d.type = "bar";
        });
    }
```

This turns a line graph into bar graph (path to rects), also i need with an event, set those bars into lines again, a switcher more specifically. I was trying to think how to achieve this, and one way could be reseting the entire chart when i trigger the event in order to restore the initial line.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you have trouble with attaching the events, the transitions or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reset the chart to its initial state and data, just like if i refresh the page. Sry if i'm not clear enough, i'm a d3 newbie. Thanks.

Comment: You would have to create the same elements with the same attributes as when you initialised the page.